# How does /usr/bin/java work on Mac?

Tags: java

I found `/usr/bin/java` linked to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java`. And its file content is different from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`. But when I type `/usr/bin/java -version` it prints

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

So I'm curious about the implementation of /usr/bin/java and wondering why it can always point to the latest version of my JavaVirtualMachines?

Answer (score 15):

I can't fully answer your question but I have a few practical clues I can share.

**TL:DR;**

I think that `/usr/bin/java` is a proxy application, part of MacOS, that calls the `java` command in the current java installation as defined by `JAVA_HOME` env var.

And this is the same for all the java related commands in `/usr/bin`

**More details**

I have installed (manually, by unzipping the openjdks into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`) many versions of Java, and just by setting a different JAVA_HOME, the version switches:

```
$ JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_112.jdk/Contents/Home && java -version
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)

$ JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-11.jdk/Contents/Home/ && java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-11.0.11.9.1 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-11.0.11.9.1 (build 11.0.11+9-LTS, mixed mode)

$ JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/ && java -version
openjdk version "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)
```

All the Java commands in `/usr/bin` have the same size (136Kb in my case):

```
$ ll -h /usr/bin/ja*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/jar
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/jarsigner
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/javac
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/javadoc
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/javah
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/javap
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/javapackager
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   136K Jan  1  2020 /usr/bin/javaws
```

Actually, many files in `/usr/bin` are the same:

```
$ find /usr/bin | sort | xargs md5 | grep d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/appletviewer) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/apt) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/extcheck) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/idlj) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/jar) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/jarsigner) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/java) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/javac) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/javadoc) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
MD5 (/usr/bin/javah) = d50afbfa4f5d05e8db7ad88c30390888
.
.
.
```

In "System Information.app > Software > Installation" I don't find any specific installation occurred around `Jan 1 2020`, from the same I see I installed Catalina on 2019-10-12 and Big Sur on 2020-12-04 (all files in `/usr/bin` have date `Jan 1 2020`).

Also `pkgutil` doesn't tell me to which package installation the `/usr/bin/java` commands belongs:

```
$ pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/java
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/java
```

I believe it's part of MacOS and was installed (or updated) by Big Sur.

Let me know if I missed anything or have more info for a clearer picture :-)

Comment: On my installation, the various Java commands in `/usr/bin/` are in fact hard linked to one another.  31 in total, though the hard link count is 52 and I'm looking for where the other 21 might be.

Comment: On my system, the total hard link count is also 52, but 51 of them are in `/usr/bin/` and one is `/usr/libexec/java_home`. Sadly, `pkgutil --file-info ...` doesn't say about any of them from which package/app they came from

Answer (score 8):

The most complete answer I've found is this Stack Overflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-macos/44169445#44169445

In summary, `/usr/bin/java` finds all of the JVMs under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and `~/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` and points to the latest JVM that has `Contents/Info.plist`. If you rename that file in a JVM to, say, `Contents/Info.plist.disabled`, then `/usr/bin/java` will not pick it.

Comment: so I knew where my java home is but I actually curious how the /user/bin/java linked to that cause

➜  ~ ls -l /usr/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  168432  7 Feb 08:22 /usr/bin/java
➜  ~ echo "$JAVA_HOME"

➜  ~

(my JAVA_HOME env is empty), and /usr/bin/java is neither a symlink or raw text

Comment: I think /usr/bin/java is an actual program, not a symlink.